# Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames() exception because of dynamic assembly

Tags: .net, unit-testing, exception, dynamic-assemblies

If I run a unit test (mstest) I get an exception if I call `assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()`:

> The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly.

This is the problematic code:

```
Dim assembly As Assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(Me.GetType())
Dim names = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()
```

But if I understand [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcenames.aspx) right, it should work and only if I use `AssemblyBuilder.GetManifestResourceNames()` I should get this exception.

If I try to step through the .NET sources I get the message:

> There is no source available for mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.Emit.InternalAssemblyBuilder.GetManifestResourceNames()

Why does it throw this exception?  Did I miss anything?

I forget to mention that I use Moq (with the option `mock.CallBase = True`) in the test.

Comment: I found a workaround:

If I make the procedure shared (static in c#), where 'assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()' is called, it works.

Comment: You should post that as an answer to the question and then accept it! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround: If I make the procedure shared (static in c#), where 'assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()' is called, it works.

Comment: This helped me too, but it would be nice if someone could explain why the method needs to be static.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it to work with just using static, but I did find another solution.

My Setup:

1. MVC Project (website) (References 2)
2. Logic Project (References 3)
3. Content Library (only files)

My website called a method in the logic project, which tried to access the `GetManifestResourceNames()` from the content library. This resulted in the error.

I then removed the content reference from the logic project and added it directly to my website. No other changes and now it worked.